How to verifies MSI without using a module
I am using a script that checks if a file is signed and its version (dll, EXE, MSI, PS1)
Currently, the script is running from my machine, and modules are allowed to be installed, I am moving the script to a pipeline and I am not allowed to install modules in my company.
All the files can be checked except MSI, now I am using the MSI module.
Regarding the signing I can use this:
Get-AuthenticodeSignature

To know the Manufacturer I am using this:
$Manufacturer = "Manufacturer: $((Get-MSIProperty -Path $dll -Property Manufacturer).value)"

To know the version I am using this:
((Get-MSIProperty -Path $dll -Property ProductVersion).value)

Is there any way to do that without installing a module?
I saw this but it does not look the same
Get-AppLockerFileInformation -Path "" | select -ExpandProperty Publisher | select PublisherName, ProductName, BinaryVersion, BinaryName

If I am using it the version looks like this:
MajorPartNumber   : 8
MinorPartNumber   : 6
BuildPartNumber   : 56107
PrivatePartNumber : 0
VersionNumber     : 2251829260517376

How to convert to string? using .ToString() ?

Perhaps the function someone called bastienperez published can help?  Get-MSIFileInformation

Good idea, thank you
